# If $R$ is a Noetherian ring, then $R^n$ is Noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noetherian, finitely-generated

I'm working with a Noetherian ring $R$. As an $R$-module, $R^n = R \oplus ... \oplus R$. I want to show that $R^n$ is Noetherian in the sense that it obeys the ascending chain condition for its submodules (or equivalently that all submodules are finitely generated). I do not know how to do this. Because the ideals in $R^n$ don't necessarily need to "split" over the different coordinate components in the direct sum I don't know how to use the hypothesis that $R$ is Noetherian. I think this indicates perhaps we should try a contradictive proof but I don't know how to proceed with this.

Comment: In general, if
$$
0 \to N \to M \to P \to 0
$$
is an exact sequence (of $R$-modules), then
$$
M \text{ noetherian} \Longleftrightarrow N,P \text{ noetherian}.
$$
Do you know this statement? Do you see how it can help you?

Comment: @MatyMangoo Just for clarification for myself: Do you mean to use the exact sequence $0\rightarrow R\rightarrow R^n \rightarrow R^{n-1}\rightarrow 0$ and prove the statement by induction?

Comment: exactly, you start with $n = 1$ knowing $R$ is noetherian, and go by induction.

Comment: @MatyMangoo No, I do not know what an exact sequence is and I have asked this question primarily to look for an answer that doesn't require you to know about exact sequences (since most similar questions quote an exact sequence result)

Comment: Oh ok, well, then the answer from @Ayaka is more suitable for you. 
Now what is an **exact sequence**?
A **sequence** are just maps between $R$-modules
$$
 \ldots \to N \stackrel{f}{\to} M \stackrel{g}{\to} P \to \ldots \, .
$$
This can be either finite or infinite (countable) in length. The **exactness** (at $M$) means that the image of $f$ equals the kernel of $g$. 
Now saying that
$$
0 \to  N \stackrel{f}{\to} M \stackrel{g}{\to} P \to 0
$$
is exact means, it is exact at each of the modules $N,M,P$. And what does this mean?

Comment: The exactness at $N$ means, since the only map $0 \to N$ is the $0$-map, that the image of this zero map (which is $0$) equals the Kernel of $f$, and thus $f$ is injective. Similarly, the exactness at $P$ means that $g$ is surjective. But if $f$ is injective, one can understand $N$ as an $R$-submodule of $M$. and since $g$ is surjective, the homomorphism theorem tells us that
$$
M/N = M/Image(f) = M/Kern(g) = Image(g) = P.
$$
Thus, stating that (for any exact sequence as above)
$$
M \text{ noetherian} \Longleftrightarrow N,P \text{ noetherian}
$$
just means...

Comment: ... for any submodule $N \subset M$, 
$$
M \text{ noetherian} \Longleftrightarrow N \text{ and } M/N \text{ noetherian}.
$$

Comment: thank you for this introduction, can you suggest a reference on exactness theory? @MatyMangoo

Comment: I am not sure there is anything like that. You can find it here and there in some literature like e.g. Dummit, Foote- Abstract Algebra, 10.5. The 'language' of exact sequences is quite useful: as I said, any submodule $N \subset M$ gives rise to the exact sequence 
$$
0 \to N  \to M \to M/N \to 0,
$$
and as I explained above, any exact sequence of the form $0 \to N \to M \to P \to 0$ is (up to isomorphism) of this form: i.e. $N \subset M$ and $P \cong M/N$.

Comment: Now if you have an $R$-mod hom $\varphi \colon M \to M'$, this gives rise to an exact sequence of the form
$$
0 \to Kern(\varphi) \to M \to M' \to M'/Im(\varphi) \to 0.
$$
This has **four** members. On the contrary, any exact sequence with four members of the form $0 \to N \to M \to P \to Q \to 0$ is isomorphic to one induced by some $R$-mod hom. $M \to P$. Thus, exact sequences *encompass* different situations of $R$-mods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being "Noetherian" has two meanings here. (i) $R^n$ is Noetherian as a ring; (ii) $R^n$ is Noetherian as an $R$ module. If you want to show (i), you can use that any ideal $I$ of $R^n$ is split, namely there are ideals $I_1,\dots,I_n\subset R$ such that $I=I_1\oplus \cdots I_n$. You can see this by the idempotent decomposition
$$1_{R^n}=(1,0,\dots,0)+\cdots+(0,0,\dots,1)$$
as you may already know. Then, since $R$ is Noetherian, each $I_i$ is finitely generated and so is $I$. To show (ii), we can use the fact that finitely generated $R$ modules are Noetherian if $R$ is a Noetherian ring. This is elementary,
see Atiyah-MacDonald Cor. 6.4., for example. Your remark applies here, $R$-submodules of $R^n$ are not necessarily split.

Edit: Let us see (ii) by induction. The case $n=1$ is already assumed. For $n+1$, we denote by $f\colon R^{n+1}\rightarrow R^n$ the projection onto first $n$ factors. Take a chain of submodules $$S_1\subset S_2\subset \cdots$$ of $R^{n+1}$, then the chain $$f(S_1)\subset f(S_2)\subset \cdots$$
in $R^n$ terminates by induction at, say, $f(S_p)$ and similarly the chain $$S_{p}\cap \mathrm{ker}f\subset S_{p+1}\cap \mathrm{ker}f\subset \cdots$$
in $R=\mathrm{ker}f$ terminates at, say, $S_{p+q}\cap \mathrm{ker}f$.
After all, each term of the portion
$$S_{p+q}\subset S_{p+q+1}\subset \cdots$$
of the original chain has constant image and kernel with respect to $f$. We denote this common image by $I\subset R^{n}$ and kernel $K\subset R$.
For $r\geq p+q$, take $a\in S_{r}$. Then, since $f(a)\in I$, we find $b\in S_{p+q}$ with $f(a)=f(b)$. Then $c:=a-b\in S_{r}\cap \mathrm{ker}f=K$, so we see $c\in S_{p+q}$ and $a=b+c\in S_{p+q}$. Therefore, we see $S_r=S_{p+q}$ and the original chain terminates at $S_{p+q}$.

Comment: Please can you explain (ii) without the usage of exact sequences (which your reference makes use of), I'm looking for an answer that doesn't rely on these

Comment: I have edited the answer. I think you should have written explicitly what kind of proof you want in the original post for you to receive better.

Answer (score 1):

If $R$ is noetherian, the polynomial ring $R[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$ is also noetherian. Consider the ideals
$$I_k = (x_1, x_2, \dotsc, x_k-1, \dotsc, x_n).$$
The quotients $R[x_1,\dotsc, x_n]/I_k$ are isomorphic to $R$, because the variables are identified with $0$ or $1$. Also note that the $I_k$ are pairwise relatively prime, i.e.
$$I_j + I_k = R[x_1, \dotsc, x_n] \quad \text{for} \quad j \neq k.$$
By the Chinese remainder theorem you get an isomorphism
$$R[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]/I_1 \cap \dotsm \cap I_n \cong R \times \dotsm \times R,$$
and the left hand side is noetherian as a quotient of a noetherian ring.

Answer (score 0):

Your observation that the ideals of $R^n$ do not split componentwise is not correct. I asked about it [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4657821/are-ideals-in-a-ring-product-componentwise-ideals).

---

Here's a way to show it using the definition of a Noetherian ring.

A commutative ring is Noetherian if and only if every ascending chain of ideals eventually stabilizes.

**This is a proof for the ring part only, not the module part.**

#### Theorem 51: If $R$ is a Noetherian ring, then $R^n$ is a Noetherian ring.

First, let's note that multiplication in $R^n$ is componentwise, so $(a, b) \times_{\!R^2} (c, d) = (a \times_{\!R} c, b \times_{\!R} d)$.

Suppose by way of contrapositive that $R^n$ is not Noetherian, this means that it contains an infinite ascending chain of ideals:

$$ I(1) \subsetneq I(2) \subsetneq I(3) \subsetneq \cdots $$

Note that $I(i)$ it the $i$th ideal in the sequence; I'm doing this so I can select components using subscripts.

The above is equal to:

$$ \bigg(I_1(1), I_2(1) \cdots I_n(1)\bigg) \subsetneq \bigg(I_2(1), I_2(2), \cdots I_n(2)\bigg) \subsetneq \cdots $$

If every component $I_a(1) \subsetneq I_a(2) \subsetneq I_a(3) \subsetneq \cdots$ stabilized, then the whole sequence would stabilize.

Thus at least one of the components doesn't stabilize.

*End of proof of theorem 51*.

---

There's an important subtlety in the $R$-module case.

Consider the submodule $((1,2))$ in the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Each component of $((1,2))$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-ideal $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{2Z}$, however,

$((1, 2))$ is NOT equal to $\mathbb{Z} \times 2\mathbb{Z}$.

I don't have a proof at the moment that a chain of submodules with constant "component ideals" that nevertheless fails to stabilize is impossible.