# Are ideals in a ring product componentwise ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I tried to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4657490) in a brute force way.

In order to keep this question focused, **I am primarily interested in the case where $R^n$ is a ring**. It's also a perfectly cromulent $R$-module, but one thing at a time.

I assumed that $R^n$ is not Noetherian, got an infinite ascending sequence of ideals, and argued that at least one of the coordinates $k \in \{1, 2, \cdots n\}$ must give me an ascending chain of ideals in $R$ if I apply the projection $\pi_k$ to each ideal in the chain.

Then I noticed a comment in the original question **emphasis mine**:

> I'm working with a Noetherian ring $R$. As an $R$-module, $R^n=R⊕...⊕R$. I want to show that $R^n$ is Noetherian in the sense that it obeys the ascending chain condition for its submodules (or equivalently that all submodules are finitely generated). I do not know how to do this. **Because the ideals in $R^n$
> don't necessarily need to "split" over the different coordinate components in the direct sum I don't know how to use the hypothesis that $R$
> is Noetherian.** I think this indicates perhaps we should try a contradictive proof but I don't know how to proceed with this.

So, again thinking of $R^n$ as a ring for concreteness, why is this true?

$R^n$ has componentwise addition and componentwise multiplication, by definition.

By considering ring elements of the form $(1, \cdots, r_i, \cdots, 1)$, I think I can argue that each individual component of an ideal $I$ or $R^n$ must itself be an ideal of $R$.

**What am I missing about this remark that ideals don't split into different components?**

Comment: The remark is just wrong

Comment: The distinction to be made here is that a general submodule of $R^n$ need not split into a direct sum of submodules of each component. But an *ideal* of $R^n$ will always split into a direct sum of ideals. The difference is that ideals of $R^n$ are closed under multiplication by elements of $R^n$ (so we can multiply by $(1,0,0...,0)$), whereas submodules of $R^n$ (as an $R$-module) are only closed under multiplication by elements of $R$ (so we can't use multiplication to "project"). But the remark is still wrong, since it talks about ideals of $R^n$...

Comment: @KenanskiBowspleefi Ah. I think I get it now. With a $\mathbb{Z}$-module like $\mathbb{Z}^2$, the submodule $((1,2))$ is NOT $\mathbb{Z} \times 2\mathbb{Z}$, even though you get $\mathbb{Z}$ or $2 \mathbb{Z}$ respectively if you walk the elements of $((1,2))$ and project the first or second coordinate.